# How to rename a sqlite column in python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I got this code to change a column name in an sqLite database in python:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''ALTER TABLE products RENAME COLUMN buying_options TO shipping_options''',conn)
conn.commit()
```

with output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-1a4a76805a4c> in <module>
      1 conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
      2 cursor = conn.cursor()
----> 3 cursor.execute('''ALTER TABLE products RENAME COLUMN buying_options TO shipping_options''',conn)
      4 conn.commit()
      5 test_df =  pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM products',conn)

ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

My data base looks as follows:

```
test_df =  pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM products',conn)
test_df.columns
```

gives

```
Index(['product_id', 'seller', 'title', 'views', 'tags', 'nr_of_sales',
       'origin_country', 'ships_to', 'category', 'link', 'description',
       'payment_type', 'class', 'buying_options', 'listing_date',
       'product_class', 'nr_of_options', 'nr_of_reviews', 'usd_price'],
      dtype='object')
```

I have no clue what is going wrong, the syntax should be correct right? I am running sqlite 3.31

Comment: You are not supposed to pass `conn` to `cursor.execute()`

Comment: Remove the `conn` argument: `cursor.execute('''ALTER TABLE products RENAME COLUMN buying_options TO shipping_options''')`.

Comment: Thanks! I feel silly for missing this mistake, but I got stuck on it unnecessarily long ...

Comment: Lesson to learn: Consult the documentation earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try by change

`cursor.execute('''ALTER TABLE products RENAME COLUMN buying_options TO shipping_options''',conn)`

to

`cursor.execute('''ALTER TABLE products RENAME COLUMN buying_options TO shipping_options''')`

you can find more on this website:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html